# Install windows 10 on self built PC from usb, internet required?

Tags: windows-installer

I want to install Windows 10 on a PC I am building, specifically onto a SSD. I understand the steps of getting the  windows files onto a USB.

My question is that do I need internet connection on the computer I am building to install from USB? If so how do I connect to the Internet with no operating system (computer builder novice here)?  If not, is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: An internet connection is not required to install Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need internet, just insert the usb with the mounted iso image.

Install Windows by inserting it into your pc, it boot up the installation if it's in the correct boot order.

once the installations done, download the correct driver for your wireless card or whatever using another device which has access to the internet or maybe the CD that came with the wireless card, and install.

Run updates, and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not. You can activate the license later.
Your steps are

1. copy a windows iso file on a usb or burn it to a dvd
2. while windows running double click on the drive and click install

You can get the iso file [here](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10) (official Microsoft website). Here you can find a [full tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-from-a-USB-Flash-Drive).

Comment: cite and quote your link.